# How do I insert an HTML element in the Firefox inspector tool?

Tags: html, firefox

I need to be able insert new HTML elements in Firefox Inspector Tool, but I can't find any way.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376594/how-do-i-insert-an-html-element-in-the-google-chrome-inspector) is a similar question but it asks about the Google Chrome inspector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using the inspector tool, go to the inspector tab, right click anywhere in the page where you want to inspect and choose Inspect Element, an icon will appear on the page on that element, click on that icon and you will find "Edit as HTML". 
Attached is a screenshot. [image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. However, it only was possible for me to `Edit as HTML` if I had the mouse pointer into the Inspector's elements, not on the browser as you show on the screenshot. Did I miss somethng?

Answer (score 1):

You need to right click on the parent element and select EDIT HTML. This will let you type freely, and you can add any tags you wish inside.

Answer (score 0):

you can right-click and edit the inner html. this is because the browser cannot know beforehand what kind of item you want to add. so the option they leave is edit html.

sorry... the answer is quite a duplicate of the answer you left for chrome. but AFAIK is the annoying truth.